# Uploading to a specific folder to Skydrive

Tags: c#, windows-runtime

So I know that the code to upload a file to skydrive is

```
LiveAuthClient authClient = new LiveAuthClient();
LiveLoginResult authResult = await authClient.LoginAsync(new List<string>() { "wl.basic", "wl.skydrive", "wl.skydrive_update" });
if (authResult.Status == LiveConnectSessionStatus.Connected)
{
    LiveConnectClient meClient = new LiveConnectClient(authResult.Session);

    StorageFolder storageFolder = KnownFolders.DocumentsLibrary;
    StorageFile sampleFile = await storageFolder.CreateFileAsync("sample.txt");
    await Windows.Storage.FileIO.WriteTextAsync(sampleFile, "Sample Content");

    LiveOperationResult result = await meClient.BackgroundUploadAsync("me/skydrive/testFolder", sampleFile.Name, sampleFile, OverwriteOption.Overwrite);
}
```

and the code to make a folder is

```
LiveAuthClient authClient = new LiveAuthClient();
LiveLoginResult authResult = await authClient.LoginAsync(new List<string>() { "wl.basic", "wl.skydrive", "wl.skydrive_update" });
try
{
    var folderData = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    folderData.Add("name", "Test Folder");
    LiveConnectClient liveClient = new LiveConnectClient(authResult.Session);
    LiveOperationResult operationResult =
        await liveClient.PostAsync("me/skydrive", folderData);
    dynamic result = operationResult.Result;
}
catch (LiveConnectException exception)
{
}
```

How would get the folder ID from the folder that I made and then upload the file to that location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
LiveAuthClient authClient = new LiveAuthClient();
LiveLoginResult authResult = await authClient.LoginAsync(new List<string>() { "wl.basic", "wl.skydrive", "wl.skydrive_update" });
try
{
    var folderData = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    folderData.Add("name", "Test Folder");
    LiveConnectClient liveClient = new LiveConnectClient(authResult.Session);
    LiveOperationResult operationResult =
        await liveClient.PostAsync("me/skydrive", folderData);
    dynamic result = operationResult.Result;
    var folderId = result.id;

    /*result is dynamic object, you can get the folder id with id property 
    operationResult.RawResult will return JSON response with some data related to 
    that folder */
}
catch (LiveConnectException exception)
{
}
```

Comment: Thanks. If the folder already exists, how would I get the folderID of that folder?

Comment: You need to parse/deserialize the JSON response and get the ID of particular folder.

Comment: I find that `PostAsync` throws an error if I try the above on a folder that exists, so I can't get the ID... There's a solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18983166/upload-to-a-specific-folder-skydrive